# How to call a function inside a function in Swift 3

Tags: function, swift3, xcode8, uitapgesturerecognizer

I try to call a function `tapBlarButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` in `viewWillAppear` function but I don't know how to do it, this is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonFunction: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapBlarButton(_:)))

    buttonFunction.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

}

func tapBlarButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("Hello! ")

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Here I want to call the function

}
```

Comment: declare it as `func tapBlarButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {`

Comment: and call it there `tapBlarButton()`

Comment: Thanks, Leo Dabus ❤️

Comment: If you would like me to post my comment as the answer please let me know otherwise feel free to just delete your question

Comment: I would like create a if statement like this: if tapGesture is touched { print("woooow") }   How did I do this?

Comment: No need to add a tap gesture recognizer to a button. Just create an IBAction

Comment: Control click your button and drag it to connect to your view controller

Comment: Select connection: Action, give a name to your method, select type UIButton for event touch up inside with argument sender

Comment: it should result in this `@IBAction func tapBlarButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
     print("Hello! ") }`

Comment: And delete the UITapGestureRecognizer stuff